# what is the step to save to and load xml file?

Tags: java, xml, tree, binary-search-tree

what is the step to save to and load xml file?what is the step to save to and load xml file?

```
    if (element.getElementsByTagName(Customer.KEY_NAME).getLength() > 0) {
        name = element.getElementsByTagName(Customer.KEY_NAME).item(0).getTextContent();
    }
```

I have a question regarding the item(0) part in this code. Why is it used as item(0) instead of item(i)? I'm not sure why the code is fetching only the first element instead of iterating through multiple elements. Can you explain the purpose of using item(0) here and why it's not item(i)?"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1FA9.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tm6A9.png)

Comment: You need to edit your question and provide more details about the task.  Why *would* the code need to iterate over multiple elements?  What is your program trying to do?

Comment: getElementsByTagName is getting the node plus all the descendants of the Node.   Index zero is just getting the parent without the descendants.

Answer (score 0):

Your code likely parsed some input document into a DOM structure.
Then it tries to use the element customer.KEY_NAME (we do not know the tag name as that is stored in a constant).

First there is a check whether that element is contained in the DOM: `element.getElementsByTagName(Customer.KEY_NAME)` returns the list of all elements with that name. You might expect exactly one such element - but XML per se would allow none or multiple as well. If that list contains entries the value needs to be retrieved.

So again the method `element.getElementsByTagName(Customer.KEY_NAME)` is called which returns a list, and since we expect exactly one entry in that list it is sufficient to work on the first one. The first one is retrieved with `.item(0)`.

Now you have the KEY_NAME element but you need to have the text content - hence the .getTextContent() method is called and the result is stored in the `name` variable.

Coming back to your question: You would write something like `item(i)` if you tried to iterate over the list of KEY_NAME elements. If your document structure might contain several such elements that are required to evaluate this would indeed be the better solution. And that is where I believe your document will contain only one such value.

The truth therefore is: What nature is your input document and how do you want to evaluate it?

Answer (score 0):

/////////xml-save

public void save(String tableName, List customers) {

```
    File f = new File(FileUtil.getTableFileName(tableName));

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        // make the xml tree
        // use factory to get the instance of document builder
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.newDocument();
        // Root element <customers>
        Element rootElem = doc.createElement(Customer.KEY_ROOT);
        doc.appendChild(rootElem);

        for (Customer customer : customers) {
            Element customerElem = doc.createElement(Customer.KEY_ELEMENT);
            rootElem.appendChild(customerElem);

            // child element <ID> under <customer>
            Element cid = doc.createElement(Customer.KEY_ID);
            cid.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(Integer.toString(customer.getId())));
            customerElem.appendChild(cid);

            if (customer.getName() != null) {
                Element name = doc.createElement(Customer.KEY_NAME);
                name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(customer.getName()));
                customerElem.appendChild(name);
            }

            if (customer.getAddress() != null) {
                Element address = doc.createElement(Customer.KEY_ADDRESS);
                address.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(customer.getAddress()));
                customerElem.appendChild(address);
            }

            if (customer.getCity() != null) {
                Element city = doc.createElement(Customer.KEY_CITY);
                city.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(customer.getCity()));
                customerElem.appendChild(city);
            }

            if (customer.getPostCode() != null) {
                Element postCode = doc.createElement(Customer.KEY_POSTCODE);
                postCode.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(customer.getPostCode()));
                customerElem.appendChild(postCode);
            }

            if (customer.getCountry() != null) {
                Element country = doc.createElement(Customer.KEY_COUNTRY);
                country.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(customer.getCountry()));
                customerElem.appendChild(country);
            }
        }
        // save the xml file
        // Transformer is for process XML from a variety of sources and write the
        // transformation
        // output to a variety of sinks
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();

        // set xml encoding to utf-8
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-8");
        // pretty print
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(f);
        transformer.transform(source, result);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

//////xml load
public List load(String tableName) {

```
    List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();

    File f = new File(FileUtil.getTableFileName(tableName));
    if (!f.exists()) {
        return customers;
    }

    // TODO: Complete this method
    // START YOUR CODE
    try {
        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(f);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName(Customer.KEY_ELEMENT);

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element element = (Element) node;

                int id = Integer.parseInt(element.getElementsByTagName(Customer.KEY_ID).item(0).getTextContent());

                String name = null, address = null, city = null, postcode = null, country = null;

                if (element.getElementsByTagName(Customer.KEY_NAME).getLength() > 0)
                    name = element.getElementsByTagName(Customer.KEY_NAME).item(0).getTextContent();

                if (element.getElementsByTagName(Customer.KEY_ADDRESS).getLength() > 0)
                    address = element.getElementsByTagName(Customer.KEY_ADDRESS).item(0).getTextContent();

                if (element.getElementsByTagName(Customer.KEY_CITY).getLength() > 0)
                    city = element.getElementsByTagName(Customer.KEY_CITY).item(0).getTextContent();

                if (element.getElementsByTagName(Customer.KEY_POSTCODE).getLength() > 0)
                    postcode = element.getElementsByTagName(Customer.KEY_POSTCODE).item(0).getTextContent();

                if (element.getElementsByTagName(Customer.KEY_COUNTRY).getLength() > 0)
                    country = element.getElementsByTagName(Customer.KEY_COUNTRY).item(0).getTextContent();

                Customer customer = new Customer(id, name, address, city, postcode, country);
                customers.add(customer);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

/////pre-order bst
public class ParcelBST extends BinarySearchTree implements Iterable  {

```
public ParcelBST(Parcel value, ParcelBST leftNode, ParcelBST rightNode) {
    super(value, leftNode, rightNode);
}

public ParcelBST(BinarySearchTree<Parcel> parcelBST) {
    //这里写了root是value
    super(parcelBST.value,parcelBST.leftNode,parcelBST.rightNode);
}

public ParcelBST(Tree<Parcel> parcelTree) {
    super(parcelTree.value,parcelTree.leftNode,parcelTree.rightNode);
}

public ParcelBST(Parcel value) {
    super(value);
}


@Override
public Iterator<Parcel> iterator() {
    return new IteratorPreOrder();
}

class IteratorPreOrder implements Iterator<Parcel> {
    // Hint: value, left/right sub-trees can be accessed by:
    //    ParcelBST.this.value    ParcelBST.this.leftNode   ParcelBST.this.rightNode
    // Or equivalently directly:
    //    value   leftNode    rightNode

    private Deque<BinarySearchTree<Parcel>> stack = new LinkedList<>();

    // You may add methods and variables here if you wish
    //这个方法是干什么？

    public IteratorPreOrder() {
        //初始preorder的迭代器
        // You may add code here if you wish
        //为什么要用外部类?
        //检查的有没有根节点，如果根节点

        if(ParcelBST.this.value != null){
            stack.push(ParcelBST.this);
        }
    }

    //在这个迭代器里，再去写方法

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        // TODO
        // START YOUR CODE
        //是用来判断stack里有没有东西的
        if(stack.isEmpty()){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
        // END YOUR CODE
    }

    @Override
    //这个方法是为了去迭代树
    public Parcel next() {
        // TODO
        // START YOUR CODE
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

        BinarySearchTree<Parcel> current = stack.pop();

        //right
        if (current.rightNode != null && current.rightNode.value != null) {
            stack.push((BinarySearchTree<Parcel>) current.rightNode);
        }

        //left
        if (current.leftNode != null && current.leftNode.value != null) {
            stack.push((BinarySearchTree<Parcel>) current.leftNode);
        }
        // END YOUR CODE
        //返回整个curren的value
        return current.value;
    }
}
```

///parser

```
public void parseExp() {

    // TODO: Complete this method
    // START YOUR CODE

    Token token1 = tokeniser.takeNext();
    Token token2 = tokeniser.takeNext();

    if (token1 == null || token2 == null)
        return; // If any token is null, return without parsing

    // Validate the brackets
    if (!token1.value.contains("(") || !token1.value.contains(")") || !token2.value.contains("(") || !token2.value.contains(")"))
        return; // Return if brackets are missing in any token

    // Extract and validate column names
    String columnsStr = token1.value.substring(token1.value.indexOf("(") + 1, token1.value.indexOf(")")).trim();
    String[] columns = columnsStr.split(",");
    List<String> validColumns = Arrays.asList(Customer.KEY_ID, Customer.KEY_NAME, Customer.KEY_ADDRESS, Customer.KEY_CITY,
            Customer.KEY_POSTCODE, Customer.KEY_COUNTRY);
    for (String column : columns) {
        if (!validColumns.contains(column.trim())) {
            return; // Return if any column name is invalid
        }
    }

    // Extract and validate values
    String valuesStr = token2.value.substring(token2.value.indexOf("(") + 1, token2.value.indexOf(")")).trim();
    String[] values = valuesStr.split(",");

    // Assuming values should match the columns
    if (columns.length != values.length)
        return; // Return if columns and values count do not match

    // Execute the SQL command (Inserting into XMLTable in this case)
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    // Assuming the order of columns matches the order in the Customer class
    customer.setId(Integer.parseInt(values[0].trim()));
    customer.setName(values[1].trim().replace("'", ""));
    customer.setAddress(values[2].trim().replace("'", ""));
    customer.setCity(values[3].trim().replace("'", ""));
    customer.setPostCode(values[4].trim().replace("'", ""));
    customer.setCountry(values[5].trim().replace("'", ""));

    table.insert(Customer.TABLE_NAME, customer); // Inserting the customer into the XMLTable

    // END YOUR CODE
}
```

}

////tokenizer

public void next() {
buffer = buffer.trim(); // remove whitespace

```
    if(buffer.isEmpty()) {
        currentToken = null;    // if there's no string left, set currentToken null and return
        return;
    }

    // ########## YOUR CODE STARTS HERE ##########
    String regex = "([A-Za-z]+)|([0-9]+)|([^A-Za-z0-9])";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(buffer);

    if(matcher.find()){
        String matechedSubString = matcher.group();

        if(Character.isLowerCase(matechedSubString.charAt(0))){
            if(containUpperCase(matechedSubString)){
                if(matechedSubString.length() <=3){
                    currentToken = new Token(matechedSubString, Token.Type.SHORT_CAMEL_CASE_WORD);
                }else {
                    currentToken = new Token(matechedSubString, Token.Type.LONG_CAMEL_CASE_WORD);
                }
            }else {
                currentToken = new Token(matechedSubString, Token.Type.LOWER_CASE_WORD);
            }
        } else if (Character.isUpperCase(matechedSubString.charAt(0))) {
            if (containLowerCase(matechedSubString)) {
                if (matechedSubString.length() <= 3) {
                    currentToken = new Token(matechedSubString, Token.Type.SHORT_CAMEL_CASE_WORD);
                } else {
                    currentToken = new Token(matechedSubString, Token.Type.LONG_CAMEL_CASE_WORD);
                }
            } else {
                currentToken = new Token(matechedSubString, Token.Type.UPPER_CASE_WORD);
            }
        } else if (Character.isDigit(matechedSubString.charAt(0))) {
            currentToken = new Token(matechedSubString, Token.Type.INTEGER_NUMBER);
        }else {
            currentToken = new Token(matechedSubString, Token.Type.NON_ALPHANUMERIC);
        }
    }

    // ########## YOUR CODE ENDS HERE ##########

    // Remove the extracted token from buffer
    int tokenLen = currentToken.getValue().length();
    buffer = buffer.substring(tokenLen);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).